# Simulate weathering of a rock

Tags: code-golf, grid, random, matrix

*Inspired by my geography class*, [*Sandboxed*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/23999#23999)

Simulate weathering / erosion.

#### Input

Input will be given as a string of any 2 characters (or see below) you like in the shape of the rock (here i use spaces and hashes):

```
   ###
  ####
 #####
#######
#######
########
```

Or if your language doesn't support strings, a square matrix of 1s and 0s, a matrix of chars, whatever makes your answer more golfier.

## Process

The rock will erode until it disappears completely.
Lets take example of input:

```
    ##
 ## ### #
#########
###########
```

First we find which part of the rock is exposed (that is there is no rock particle directly above / below / left / right) to the air (i use @ to show such particles here):

```
    @@
 @@ @#@ @
@##@###@@
@########@@
```

NOTE: The bottom most rock particles are touching the ground and they are not touching air, hence we don't count these particles.

Then we randomly (50% chance individually for each particle) remove the rock particles (here #) (apply gravity similar to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/235493/103854) that are exposed to the air:

```
    #
    ##  
 ## ### #
##########
```

And be repeat the process until the rock disappears and output the rock in between each iteration (including the original input). In this case we output:

```
    ##
 ## ### #
#########
###########
    #
    ##  
 ## ### #
##########
     
       
 ## ## 
 #########
     
       
 #  #  
 ## #### #
     
        
 #    
 #  # # #
     
        
      
 #    #
```

This is code-golf, answer in the shortest amount of bytes wins.

Comment: Apply gravity... But a rock in shape `"###/#.#/###"` is possible in real life. And the `#` in top middle will not fail down.

Comment: Can we output with additional leading/trailing spaces (e.g. input `"# #\n# #\n###"` would be output in the first iteration as `" # # \n # # \n ### "` - the output will always be two wider than the input with padded spaces)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, you can

Comment: @tsh But then you can technically have some rock like `'##\n\n###'` which is *not* possible in real life.

Comment: @Edward what do you mean?

Comment: Do we output the final step where there is no more rock?

Comment: @att No, there is not need to and it is not required.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 58 bytes

```
≔Ｅθ⁰ηＷＳＵＭη⁺κ⁼#§ιλ⊞η⁰Ｗ⌈η«Ｍι↓↑Ｅη×#κ⸿ＵＭη↨¹Ｅκ∨‹μ⌊⟦§η⊖λ⊖κ§η⊕λ⟧‽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Nb8MgDIbPza9A4WIkKnXX9tStO0RqtGgfp20HlKCCAiSFpK007bcz0w91sQQy5rHf17USvu6EiXEdgt45KEUPe04WjBPFVtlRaSMJFK4fh7fBa7cDxghCT521wjWgOKnMGKDl5Hk/ChMgpzkn66FwjTyB5sQwjFVWjUElenGfWoqTtqMFhSN/slnZHWRqWG66o0NqVqHeAMuPnifF1PyurbwqtOepVyb/8nl6TY09iiDh4dKM/l48bGUIYLGi3Vn58@YT6Y2svbTSDbIB9DwttOy@E7KFm7Df@PuKop2Fy7K/MRIMStNNspTQdDCnt/ifU5rF@cH8AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Assumes input is a rectangular newline-terminated list of strings. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅθ⁰ηＷＳＵＭη⁺κ⁼#§ιλ
```

Calculate the height of each column of the rock.

```
⊞η⁰
```

Add a padding entry to prevent wrapping.

```
Ｗ⌈η«
```

Repeat until the rock has been eroded away.

```
Ｍι↓
```

Leave space to display the rock.

```
↑Ｅη×#κ
```

Output the rock.

```
⸿
```

Leave a blank line between rocks. (Otherwise they just crash into each other making the output impossible to interpret.)

```
ＵＭη↨¹Ｅκ∨‹μ⌊⟦§η⊖λ⊖κ§η⊕λ⟧‽
```

For each column, for each particle, check whether it's exposed, and add up all of the unexposed particles and randomly the exposed particles.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 42 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0ì€Ć[ø€{ø=ÐSO_#ø‚εεDTÂ‚00.:ø}}`ø‚øεøεSÚΩ}J
```

I/O as a list of equal-sized strings, with digits `0` for spaces and `1` for rocks. The output will be two wider than the input, due to a leading/trailing column of spaces/`0`s.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f4PCaR01rjrRFH94BpKsP77A9PCHYP14ZyG2YdW7rua0uIYebgEwDAz2rwztqaxPAEod3nNsKwsGHZ51bWev1/3@0koGBgSEQGhgo6YDZhjC2IYJtCGYbYmFDgVIsAA) or [try it online pretty-printed](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V@j5JlXUFqiUFCUWlJSqVtQlJlXkppipaCk43Jotw6XkmNySWlijkImSBFQ1F7P6dzWRw3zlBVCHjUsrLU9tM3@v8HhNY@a1hxpiz68A0hXH97B5afkXwoyNLMktSixJDM/T@HwfpBmW7BMCboUNsvPbQ0BWwOyBegQoD1chycE@8crAy1pmHVu67mtLiGHm4BMAwM9q8M7amsTwBKHd5zbCsLBh2edW1nr9f@/goKCMhAqKHCBWMoQljKUBRbhUgZzlSE8JK4ylIsMAA).

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, because `ø` works on lists of strings. In the new 05AB1E version, most of the `ø` should be `€SøJ` instead.

**Explanation:**

```python
0ì€Ć                   # Add a leading/trailing 0 to each line of the (implicit)
                       # input-list:
0ì                     #  Prepend a 0 in front of each line
  €                    #  Map over each line:
   Ć                   #   Enclose it, appending its own head
[                      # Then start an infinite loop:
 ø€{ø                  #  Apply gravity:
 ø                     #   Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
  €{                   #   Sort each row
    ø                  #   Zip/transpose back
     =                 #  Print the result with newline (without popping)
     Ð                 #  Triplicate the current result
      S                #  Convert the top one to a flattened list of digits
       O               #  Sum this list
        _              #  If it's 0:
         #             #   Stop the infinite loop
      ø                #  Zip/transpose the top; swapping rows/columns
       ‚               #  Pair it with its untransposed list
        ε              #  Map over this pair:
         ε             #   Map over each row:
          D            #    Duplicate the current row
           T           #    Push 10
            Â          #    Bifurcate it; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
             ‚         #    Pair them together: [10,"01"]
              00.:     #    Replace all "10" and "01" in the copy with "00"
                  ø    #    Create cell-pairs of the row and modified row
        }}             #  Close both maps
          `            #  Pop and push both separated to the stack
           ø           #  Transpose the top copy back
            ‚          #  Pair them back together
             ø         #  Transpose this pair of matrices
              ε        #  Map over each pair of rows
               ø       #   Zip/transpose to pair together cell-pairs
                ε      #   Map over each pair of cells-pairs:
                 S     #    Convert it to a flattened list of four digits
                  Ú    #    Uniquify it
                   Ω   #    Pop and push a random value from this list
                }      #   Close the inner map
                 J     #   Join the list of characters back to a string-line
```

I'm not happy with `` }}`ø‚øεøεSÚΩ}J `` at all, but I'm unable to find something shorter to concat the values of two matrices. Adding values of two matrices together is no problem, since that is just `+`, but concatenation on the other hand.. (An equal-bytes alternative for this portion could be `` }}`øδ+εNèεÚΩ}J ``.)
[Feel free to try and find something shorter here.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/4fCORw2zDu84txWEvQ7POrey1ksBDGJ1uICy57Zon9vqd3gFUAGGHFDG6PASdI2xOv//R0dHqzs6qusoqDs5gUhnZxDp4qIeq6MQre7qCuK5uYFId3cQ6eEBkfH0BPG8vECktzeI9PFRjwVJwcyD6AWqA6uHmA4xCagLLAaxC2Iu0AywGNBmiC0wE2MB)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 356 bytes

```
import random as r,re
y=lambda _:[' ','#'][r.choice([0,1])]
g=lambda x:[*map(''.join,zip(*[(' '*(len(x)-i.count('#')))+('#'*i.count('#'))for i in zip(*x)]))]
f=lambda x:[w:=g([re.sub('#' if not i else'#(?=[^#])|(?<=[^#])#',y,a)for i,a in enumerate(x)])]+(f(w)if any(i.strip()for i in w)else[])
h=lambda x:[*map('\n'.join,f([f' {i} 'for i in x.split('\n')]))]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-n0`, 99 bytes

I'm hoping to continue working on this tonight, but this is a start (which I *think* covers the requirements?)

Accepts a rectangular multi-line string of `1`s and `0`s which are transliterated from `#` and space in the link.

```perl
while(/1/){say;/
/;($-)=@-;s/1(?!1)|(?<!1)1|(?<=0.{$-})1/0|rand 2/ges;1while s/1(.{$-})0/0${1}1/gs}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU3RCoMwDHzvV3TWh/ahphnsqRP3K46JE6RKqwyp/fV17Yawg@SO3CWZOzte4gaUgULQhLj1Tl27eTLbwSx0y@Nk2qoghSYhvp7D2HFAED7FNBDQvJSivkntAHlzQrHz5poIM9eq8qUMAkHttjUPeoa@cxq/Z2je@PkKVOkxIPQuxOOpjjSBsdwpyYLlSpod@NeMvad5GSbjolTmAw)

Comment: @PyGamer0 Hmmm, it should be, it includes this code: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@fS99aQ0VX09ZB15rLsDwjMydVoVjfUEOvWkW3VtNA30Cl2rDWUD@9@P9/QwMDIIIAQy4DZMBlaGhoYGgIJaE8A4jIv/yCksz8vOL/ugYFAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") Did you see a specific example that was broken?

Comment: Seems to be working, my eyes have deceived me.